# Solution of a non-linear system

Tags: nonlinear-system, systems-of-equations

What is the solution of the following system?

$$
\begin{align}
a \cdot e-b \cdot d & =\alpha \\
a \cdot f-c \cdot d & =\beta \\
b \cdot f-c \cdot e & =\gamma
\end{align}
$$

Where the unknowns $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are real numbers and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are fixed real numbers.

I tried to solve it by giving it some geometric meaning, but failed.

Comment: I'd try to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form

Comment: What operation does $a.e$ represent? Should it be $a\cdot e$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the system can actually be interpreted as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}d\\e\\f\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}\gamma\\-\beta\\\alpha\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\times$ is the vector cross product.

Answer (score 0):

The resultant of the first two equations with respect to variable $a$ is
$bdf - cde + \alpha f - \beta e$.  You can solve this and the third equation as
linear equations in $e,f$ (assuming $\alpha c - \beta b \ne 0$).